# How do I remove rows from dataframe A that match rows in dataframe B, when both dataframes have different number of rows?

Tags: r

I have two dataframes, each with one column, "email." dataframe A has 60K rows, B has 700.

I want to remove from A all the emails that are in B.

Running this did not do what I want.

```
merge(A, B, "email", all=T)
```

Comment: pls add sample data if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way using base R:

```
A_new <- A[!(A$email %in% B$email), ]
```

An example would be as follows

```
> a <- c(1:10, 1:10)
> a <- paste0(a, "@hotmail.com")
> b <- c("2@hotmail.com", "3@hotmail.com", "4@hotmail.com")
> c <- a[!(a %in% b) ]
> c
 [1] "1@hotmail.com"  "5@hotmail.com"  "6@hotmail.com"  "7@hotmail.com" 
 [5] "8@hotmail.com"  "9@hotmail.com"  "10@hotmail.com" "1@hotmail.com" 
 [9] "5@hotmail.com"  "6@hotmail.com"  "7@hotmail.com"  "8@hotmail.com" 
[13] "9@hotmail.com"  "10@hotmail.com"
```

Comment: cefh, as with questions, it is much preferable to include text instead of images. Most reasons are relevant only to questions. Some reasons are slightly less obvious but still important, including: it breaks screen readers *hard*; search engines don't read them, so searches will not find it; mobile device screen size might be a limiting factor. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3358272. Can you please? copy the output from your console, edit the answer, paste, and if you aren't familiar with code formatting, highlight it all and press `Ctrl-K`. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 2):

One option, using the `sqldf` library:

```
library(sqldf)
sql <- "SELECT a.*
        FROM A a LEFT JOIN B b
            ON a.email = b.email
        WHERE b.email IS NULL"
A <- sqldf(sql)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `dplyr` version:

```
anti_join(A, B, by = "email")
```

Comment: When I run this, the anti-join doesn't happen. I get this message in console: `Warning message:
Column 'email' joining factors with different levels, coercing to character vector`

Comment: First convert the `email` column in the `A` and `B` data.frames to character with `as.character()`.